# Can I lock read and write operations from Firestore of client side?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

Can I lock read and write operations from Firestore of client side? I want that only Firebase Cloud Functions can read and write in Firestore.

I was connect directly from client to Firestore but I want now the client can call only with back-end ( To make some condition and security ) server for avoiding hack data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple, you have to deny all access as follows:

```
// Deny read/write access to all users under any conditions
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Since Cloud Functions interact with Firestore through the Admin SDK they completely bypass the Security Rules.